# how make Hexa must be 2 Digit on NSData

Tags: iphone, hex, nsdata

I try use encrypt aes on iphone and success, but the result i want on nsdata must be 2 digit hexa, i try to print the result of cipher whit this code :

```
unsigned char ciphertext[16];
....
...
...
...
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(ciphertext); i++) {
    NSLog(@"ciphertext[%d] : %x ",i,ciphertext[i]);

}
```

The result is :

ciphertext[0] : 43 
ciphertext[1] : d4 
ciphertext[2] : a5 
ciphertext[3] : ee 
ciphertext[4] : 24 
ciphertext[5] : a5 
ciphertext[6] : 31 
ciphertext[7] : 62 
ciphertext[8] : 1c 
ciphertext[9] : 99 
ciphertext[10] : 88 
ciphertext[11] : 29 
ciphertext[12] : d6 
ciphertext[13] : 97 
**ciphertext[14] : 7  <== this is problem, how make this to be 07 ?** 
ciphertext[15] : 44

Please help me to make this hexa to 2 digit ?
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
NSLog(@"ciphertext[%d] : %02x ",i,ciphertext[i]);
```

See the [IEEE printf specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) for further options, that is referenced by the [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) doc.

To store your `char[]` to a NSData, you could do:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:ciphertext length:16];
```